# Design Pattern for Task Notification System

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern, command-pattern

I am looking a good design pattern that takes a combination of a Observer Design Pattern and Command Design Pattern.

Observer Design Pattern:

- Subject - ISystem
- ConcreteSubject - "Different Types of Systems"
- Observer - INotifier
- ConcreteObserver - "Different Types of Notifier's"

Command Design Pattern: Used to create a task. "Different Types of Task"

If anyone know of any good resource I can use or have done something related to what I am looking for please share?

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

> Command Design Pattern: Used to create a task. "Different Types of Task"

If you need a deign pattern for handling different tasks I'd sugest the state pattern.
I once implemented VoIP application using the observable pattern in combination with the state pattern, it worked great for that particular problem, e.g peforming different tasks depending on the current state.

Please give us a more concrete example of the problem you need to solve, different patterns solve different problems :)

Comment: User selects predefined task and send a notification automatically based on the task that was selected.
ex: Check Files
Steps
1. User 1 - uploads files
2. saves the file into the database using a front end GUI
3. Sends email to user 2 to check the files
4. User 2 checks the files and fills the missing portion 
5. User 2 saves the changes and file is complete 

Case 1: I want step 3 to fire automatically as soon as file is uploaded. Case 2: User selects a task to completed and depending on the task selected, the correct notification will be sent to end user who is required to handle the task

Comment: Case1: Sounds like the standard Observable pattern should do the trick.
Case2: If there are a limited number of task-types, e.g if you can define different tasks as objects, maybe using polymorphism, then you could have an observer that sends notifications depending on the type of observable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason using command pattern is to support command queue, pending and undo/redo. If your application requires such functionality, you can combine the command pattern with the observers inside observer pattern.

```
class ICommand {
    virtual void exec() = 0;
};

class SendEmailCommand: public ICommand {
    void exec() {
        // send the email
    }
} 

class INotifier {
    virtual void update(Event event) = 0;
};

class ConcreteNotifier: public INotifier {
    void update(Event event) {
         ICommand cmd = CommandFactory::CreateCommand(event);
         push_to_command_queue(cmd);
    }
};
```